# I have this error with cucumber when running the runner"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/messages/Messages$JavaMethod"

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd

```
FAILED: runScenario("Register To website", "Optional[User Registration]")
        Runs Cucumber Scenarios
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/messages/Messages$JavaMethod
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.createSourceReference(CachingGlue.java:303)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.lambda$emitStepDefined$5(CachingGlue.java:293)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.emitStepDefined(CachingGlue.java:293)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.lambda$prepareGlue$3(CachingGlue.java:252)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.prepareGlue(CachingGlue.java:243)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:68)
```

I have this error when running cucumber with BDD and java
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VgxW.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8SSv.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5WqZ.png

UPdate :
i use this dependancies for Cucumber what is wrong with it

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots.

Comment: And check your depencies. They're wrong.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje i add the dependency can you help me which is wrong thanks

Comment: You can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` for that

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje thank you so much, but I searched it and solved by changing the versions of the dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded the dependencies then it worked because I use **java 8**
My reference is Cucumber [docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```